# Assigning a custom domain to a S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I store the uploads of my Rails application in a S3 bucket with the Paperclip gem.
A file looks then like this:

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<app-name>/signatures/attachments/000/000/082/original/<file-name>.pdf
```

These signature files are used to show to customers, so ideally they would see:

```
https://<my-domain>/<file-name>.pdf
```

But a subdomain is also fine:

```
https://files.<my-domain>/<file-name>.pdf
```

Is this possible? Or is the very dynamic nature of paperclip folders to much to handle in one domain? Would in that case this feasible?

```
https://<my-domain>/signatures/attachments/000/000/082/original/<file-name>.pdf
```

Comment: Some reasonable answers in here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756313/custom-url-with-paperclip-and-aws-s3

Comment: I can't answer this in a paperclip-specific context, because there may be other factors at play, particularly if the object isn't public... but S3 only supports directly accessing a bucket with a custom domain name (which would need to be a subdomain in your case) under two conditions: the bucket name must exactly match the domain name, and SSL isn't supported.  To relax either or both of those constraints, you use CloudFront in front of S3.  The two services are well-integrated, but signed URLs for non-public objects use a different algorithm.